# Why does a mixture of bulk $\rm Hg$ + $\rm Cd$ +$\rm Te$ melt at a much lower melting point than any of its constituents?

Tags: temperature, material-science, phase-transition, physical-chemistry

In a real life setup, a mixture of $\rm Hg$, $\rm Cd$, and $\rm Te$ melts at approximately 330 degrees Celsius. The element with the lowest melting point is Te which melts at 449.5 degrees Celsius. How is it possible that by mixing the elements together it yields an alloy with a much lower melting point than any of the individual elements.

Comment: I suspect that you misread the boiling point of mercury as its melting point.

Answer (score 3):

This question has been answered over at Chemistry Stack Exchange: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/57686/5490

Basically, the melting of a mixture of solids is more entropically favourable than the melting of the individual solids, because when the solids melt, the liquids are able to form a solution, which has greater entropy than the separated liquids. Recall that $\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S$ and the process is spontaneous when $\Delta G < 0$. The more positive $\Delta S$ is for the process, the less $T$ you need to make $\Delta G$ negative.

Note that if the original solids were able to form a solid solution (rather than a mechanical mixture) then this argument doesn't apply because it means the initial solid state *also* has greater entropy than the pure solids (so it doesn't gain entropy of mixing when it melts). Also, if any chemical compounds form between the constituents, or if they form a non-ideal solution in the liquid phase, those interactions also need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

note first that mercury is already molten at room temperature.

when you mix those three components together, no single atom of any of them is surrounded with only atoms of the same type. This means that you cannot expect the melt temperature to remain the same. Note also that their diameters are not the same which means they as an aggregate will not stack neatly together any more, which means in turn that they will not attract each other as strongly as they would as pure elements in a perfect lattice.

Comment: I was erroneous in saying Hg, Cd, Te. It is actually a mixture of solid HgTe, CdTe, and Te

Answer (score 2):

It is an interesting question, not readily amenable to a simple answer. The reason is that melting is a complex phenomenon. Its description from the viewpoint of pure thermodynamics implies the ability to predict the Gibbs free energy change between liquid and solid at different compositions. With some experience with phase diagrams of similar systems, it is possible to rationalize the empirical data, but it is not easy to be predictive.

From the viewpoint of statistical mechanics, interactions play a key role. However, an entirely satisfactory quantitative answer implies quite a sophisticated modeling of the atomic interactions in the ternary alloy.

From a general viewpoint, without any claim to be quantitative, it is possible to rationalize a lower melting point in an alloy, with respect to the pure component cases, in different ways by using some of the existing criteria for melting. A couple of possibilities are the following.

**Defect-induced mechanism**
This goes back to the idea that melting occurs when thermally activated defects start to dominate the dynamics of a solid, opening the possibility of the continuous diffusion typical of the liquid state. It is clear that defect formation strongly depends on the local chemical environment and then on the composition of the alloy. At different compositions, the local environment may cause the formation of defects more easily than in the pure systems.

**Density functional theory of freezing**
The main idea behind such a first-principles theory is that looking at melting from the liquid side, i.e., as freezing, the phenomenon can be seen as an interplay between liquid-favoring and solid-favoring contributions to the change of free energy,  expressible in terms of the values of the structure factor of the liquid phase in correspondence with the solid-state wavevectors. The so-called Hansen and Verlet criterion on the first peak of the structure factor for one component system freezing can be justified within such a theory. To the best of my knowledge, I do not know of attempts to use the theory for ternary alloys like Hg-Cd-Te. However, from the qualitative point of view, the important changes in the liquid structure factors of liquid alloys as a function of composition can easily explain a corresponding variation in melting/freezing temperature.